# Minify HTML using a Node.js module

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, minify

I have HTML in a variable and before render it and I want to minify it. I know there are console minifiers such as:

- [html-minifier](https://npmjs.org/package/html-minifier)

But I want to minify in code, like this:

```
var minifier = require ('some-minifier');
var notMinifiedHtml = "<html>...</html>";
var minifiedHtml = minifier(notMinifiedHtml);
```

But I don't know such `some-minifier` library...

Comment: Why? If you're concerned about transmitting data over the wire, use compression and forget about minification.

Comment: @MattBall because minified html loads faster on ther browser

Comment: What types of minification are you after? Whitespace removal would be somewhat easy with regex, but do you want to go further with, say, variable replacement and such?

Comment: @Ehryk You should never process HTML with regex.

Comment: @Ehryk whitespace removing would be enough

Comment: But does it actually load faster when you account for the time it takes to minify, on the server, with every request? Just sayin'.

Comment: @MattBall even if it did take more time to load, that wasn't the question asked, nor was it about all the ways to reduce page load times, nor was it 'suggest doing something else entirely.'

Comment: @mattball I use redis caching. So minify only one time.

Comment: I hope this solution link will help you https://www.programmingquest.com/2023/03/how-to-use-nodejs-for-html-minification.html

Comment: @ Alex W: Why never process HTML with regex?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

The module you specified, html-minifier, already does what you're asking for. This is how it's used:

```
var minify = require('html-minifier').minify;
var input = '<!-- foo --><div>baz</div><!-- bar\n\n moo -->';
var output = minify(input, options);
```

The options object requires at least one of the boolean flags shown below. If no flags are specified, the minifier will just return the string that was passed in as input.

```
removeComments
removeCommentsFromCDATA
collapseWhitespace
collapseBooleanAttributes
removeAttributeQuotes
removeRedundantAttributes
useShortDoctype
removeEmptyAttributes
removeOptionalTags
removeEmptyElements
```

Note that the library parses the input as HTML, not XHTML.

Comment: this only works in a node environment, i get the error: `Module not found: Can't resolve 'fs';` Any way of doing this from a from end such as a react functional component?