# Node.js Express obfuscation

Tags: obfuscation

I need help i'm a beginner in development. I create an application in NODE.JS with express js and i must protect my code with an abfuscation. i'm looking for this on internet but i didn't found any answer. Can you help me please? I must hide the html code in the inspector.

Comment: Usually people make a single executable: https://stackoverflow.com/a/53450239/1480104

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Minify HTML using a Node.js module](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19018921/minify-html-using-a-node-js-module)